# How to Reset a Value in Python String

Tags: python, string

I am trying to add certain text everytime a vowel appears in a word. Here is my code so far:

```
first_syl = 'ab'
second_syl = 'bc'
word = 'income'

vowels = "aeiou"
diction = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
empty_str = ""
word_str = ""

for ch in word:
    if ch in diction:
        word_str += ch
    if ch in vowels:
        empty_str += word_str + ch + first_syl

print (empty_str)
```

Result - iabncoabncmeab

Correct Result - iabncoabmeab

The difference is that in my program there is an extra 'nc' right before 'meab'. The problem is when the loop runs it adds first 'n', then 'nc', then 'ncm' (non vowels) but instead I need it to add 'n', then 'c', and then 'm'.

Any ideas on how to do this..? Using python 3.2.3, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to do but if your goal is to obain
 iabncoabmeab
Then you need to reset word_str after a vowel appears

```
for ch in word:
if ch in diction:
    word_str += ch
if ch in vowels:
    empty_str += word_str + ch + first_syl
    word_str="" // I don't now python but you should clear the string
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your objective right you want to add ch to empty_str on each pass then only add first_syl when you hit a vowel.

The reason you are stacking is you are += word_str each time you hit a vowel. It would just keep getting worse the more vowels in the string you provide as source.

```
for ch in word:
    empty_str += ch
    if ch in diction:
        word_str += ch
    if ch in vowels:
        empty_str +=  first_syl

print (empty_str, word_str)
```